# Show that the class of all finite unions of closed-open intervals on the real line is a ring of sets but is not a Boolean algebra of sets.

Tags: general-topology

From what I understood, a ring of sets is a non-empty class of sets that is closed under symmetric difference of any pair of sets of the class and under intersection of any pair of sets of the class.

Why isn't it a set of Boolean algebra and how do you show it to be a ring of sets? 
I have just begun Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis for context.

Comment: There is a 'general-topology' tag. By the way, what is a closed-open interval of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Like $[0,1)$. Where the first limit is included and the second not. The converse would be an open-closed interval like $(0,1]$.

Comment: I think your definition of ring of sets is different than mine one (and I suppose, many other people's), so may be you should give that definition.

Comment: Or maybe when you say "From what i understood", you mean that is your definition

Comment: This is just how the book introduced it. If possible, could you tell me your definition for a ring of sets? I just started self-studying in this area, so I don't really know any conventions.

Comment: There is more than one [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets), but you should use the one of the book. Did you try something? This seems straightforward...

Comment: I tried this for quite a while. I just didn't know how to show it isn't a boolean algebra of set. It being a ring of sets seems intuitive to me but I also don't know how to formally show it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57418/discussion-between-mrigank-arora-and-amrsa).

Answer (score 0):

A ring of sets is defined in Simmons to be a non-empty class $\mathcal{A}$ such that for $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$:

(1) $A \Delta B \in \mathcal{A}$, where $\Delta$ stands for the symmetric difference.

(2) $A \cap B \in \mathcal{A}$.

Note that this implies $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$.  For this proof, you need to show the following.  If $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{A}$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is the class of all finite unions of closed-open intervals on the real line, then $B_1 \Delta B_2 \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathcal{A}$.

To show that $\mathcal{A}$ is not a Boolean algebra of sets, consider whether $B_1'$ is in $\mathcal{A}$, where $B_1'$ stands for the complement of $B_1$.  To help you get on your way, maybe define $B_1 = [a,b)$ and $B_2 = [c,d)$ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then consider whether these two closed-open intervals are overlapping, containing one or the other, or disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

The symmetric difference $$[a,b)\Delta[c,d)=[\min(a,c),\min(b,d))\cup[\max(a,c),\max(b,d))$$ so it's clearly a member of the class of sets of unions of closed-open intervals. Similarly for the intersection. So it's easy to show this is a ring of sets.

The complement of a closed-open interval $[a,b)$ is $(-\infty,a)\cup[b,\infty)$ which is not a finite union of closed-open intervals, thus this is not a Boolean algebra of sets since it doesn't contain the complements of all members of the set.